# When I click F3 I cannot see the open windows

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

When I click F3 on my macbook to view all open windows some or all of the windows disappear or show as a small white line. This can be seen in the screenshot attached. Any ideas if this is normal or how to fix it?[image: View after clicking F3 with just safari open]

Comment: Well, the normal behaviour of Exposé (F3) is to show all open windows as you suggested. Is it the same problem for all desktops (I notice you have two desktops and one full screen program running)?

Comment: It does happen on all desktops but not necessarily all of the time. Some days it works fine, I am mainly interested in knowing if this is a common bug or if there is an issue with my mac.

Comment: This doesn't seems to be a common bug. Do you have any Exposé/Mission Control external components installed?